# How do I test the methods of with Mockito/Powermockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I have a class that needs to be unit tested:

```
public class AMQProducer {

     private final String TCP = "tcp://";
     private final String COLON = ":";

     AMQProducer() {

     }

     public AMQProducer(String ip, long port) throws JMSException {
      try {
       ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(TCP + ip + COLON + port);
       Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
      } catch (JMSException e) {
       throw e;
      }
     }
    }
```

I have a test case:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest()
public class TestAMQProducer {

 @Mock
 Connection connection;

 @Mock
 ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

 @Test
 public void test() throws Exception {
  PowerMockito.whenNew(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(connectionFactory);
  PowerMockito.when(connectionFactory.createConnection()).thenReturn(connection);
  AMQProducer producer = new AMQProducer("random", 1234);
 }
}
```

When I run the test case, the mock object of ActiveMQConnectionFactory isn't being used. Instead, the actual implementation is being used and there's a TCP connection being made:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://random:2333. Reason: java.net.UnknownHostException: random
```

I tried with Powermockito and Mockito, but failed with both. How do I mock the objects and how do I successfully run the test case?

I am new to unit testing and tried to get help from various communities, but didn't find the appropriate answer. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Initialize your mock objects in @Before method

Comment: You don't use `connection` outside of the constructor ? Are `TCP` and `COLON` really related to the domain of `AMQProducer` ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot test it with the current structure of your code - you create `new ActiveMQConnectionFactory` in your constructor. Use dependency injection instead.

With Mockito:

```
public class AMQProducer {

    AMQProducer() {}

    public AMQProducer(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws JMSException {
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    }

}

public class TestAMQProducer {

    private final Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);
    private final ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = mock(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.class);

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        doReturn(connection).when(connectionFactory).createConnection();

        // actual test here
    }

}
```